# Não aparece o "Typescript task Runner" - vsCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Abaixo está a tela que preciso encontrar no vsCode (preciso do **Tasks: Configure Task Runner**):
[image: tela do manual que estou vendo]

Mas, quando eu procuro por "tasks" na paleta de comandos (ctrl + shift + 9), essa opção não aparece:

[image: minha tela]

Sabem me informar por que não aparece?
Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece pois você deve estar usando como referência alguma vídeo-aula que utilizou a versão do VSCode menor que 1.13 [[1]](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks-v1). Nas versões mais recentes você vai encontrar apenas a opção **Tasks: Configure Default Build Task**. [[2]](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks)